# Posicionar uma imagem circular no centro

Tags: css, html5, aplicação-web, layout, img

Estou criando um site e gostaria de posicionar a imagem no centro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo"><!-- Inicio Conteudo -->
   
   <h1>Sobre Edson Luiz</h1>

   <div class="circle">
    <img src="./imgs/foto.jpg">
   </div>

   <p>Profissional ...</p>
</div><!-- Fim Conteudo -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Edson,

Alterei seu CSS, veja se atende sua necessidade. Segue exemplo da solução abaixo:

Havia considerado o atributo `left: 50%` mas o `margin: 0 auto` deixa melhor estruturado

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo"><!-- Inicio Conteudo -->
    <h1>Sobre Edson Luiz</h1>

    <div class="circle">
        <img src="./imgs/foto.jpg">
    </div>

    <p>Profissional ...</p>
</div><!-- Fim Conteudo -->
```

Abraços!

Comment: Olá Gustavo, desde já obrigado pela força. O código funcionou perfeitamente.

Fiz alguns testes e mesmo sem a parte depois de margem 0 funcionou do mesmo jetio;

.circle img {
margin: 0;
background: yellow;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

Comment: Por nada Edson, fiz um ajuste na resposta. Um colega do stackoverflow mostrou uma maneira melhor estruturada. Abraços

Answer (score 2):

Para centralizar horizontalmente o círculo, como ele é um elemento block (div), basta adicionar a propriedade:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

O primeiro valor `0` representa as margens *top/bottom* e o segundo valor `auto` as margens *direita/esquerda*. Como é `auto` de *automatic* (automático), as margens laterais serão divididas por igual e o elemento ficará centralizado no contêiner:

```css
.circle {
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo"><!-- Inicio Conteudo -->
   
   <h1>Sobre Edson Luiz</h1>

   <div class="circle">
    <img src="./imgs/foto.jpg">
   </div>

   <p>Profissional ...</p>
</div><!-- Fim Conteudo -->
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que, neste caso também seria interessante centralizar o título, incluindo uma regra css ".title { text-align: center; }" e alterando o título para "<h1 class="title">Sobre Edson Luiz</h1>".

Answer (score 0):

Elementos `<img>` são por padrão `inline-block` ou seja, você consegue aplicar estilos de bloco (como width, height, border) e eles seguem o fluxo do texto.

Partindo do princípio que a imagem já no tamanho desejado ou na proporção (no seu caso 150px x 150px), você não precisa de "hacks" usando `position`, `margin` ou `transform`

Veja:

```css
.img-circle {
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
}

.text-center {
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo"><!-- Inicio Conteudo -->
<h1>Sobre Edson Luiz</h1>
<div class="text-center ">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div><!-- Fim Conteudo -->
```